# Stop 2 intervals at the same time + make them incremental

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Today I'm trying a little bit complicated script for me.

What I have to do is change the interval that the ajax request info from the server when this is down or returns any type of error. That's the easy part and I have it already:

```
request.fail(function(data) {

    if(me.parentInterval) {
        clearInterval(me.parentInterval);
        me.startAutoRefresh(5000);
    }
});


ConsoleDataTable.prototype.startAutoRefresh = function(time) {
var me = this;

if (time == null && time == undefined)
    time = 1000;
me.parentInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (me.live) {
        me.getData();
    }
}.bind(me), time);

return me.parentInterval;
```

};

### Explanation

The function startAutoRefresh sets a parentInterval that is attributed to a Table. That table reloads it's info every second with the exception that if the server is down or something, the next request has to wait 5 seconds.

What I have to do now is:

- If the request delays more than 5 times(or server return error 5 times) the next me.startAutoRefresh has to be incremental (2 times or 5 times, does not matter). How I do to get the fail from server and know the times it failed? I tried with a variable count++ that each time I enter on the request increments, but It didn't work.
- I have a "childTable" that needs to reload it's info too. The problem is when that table request fail, it doesn't change his interval. Here you have it's code.

---

```
ConsoleDataTable.prototype.addChildTable = function(params) {
         request.done(function(data) {
                me.childTableInterval = setInterval(function(rowClicked) {
                       //Some code not relevant now//

                    if (me.live && active) {
                        tabTable.getData();
                    }

                }, 1000, rowClicked);
            });

            request.fail(function(data){
                clearInterval(me.childTableInterval);
                me.startAutoRefresh(5000);
            })
```

---

#### Pictures to illustrate you

1-This is the parentTable with it's interval. ChildTable undefined is fine because the child Table isn't present now.

2- The childTable is present. I know it drops a undefined, but It comes because I clean the interval first to prevent possible duplicates intervals ID.

3- When I stop the server, the first table (databases) waits 5 secons and it has to be incremental when X number of errors (from databases only, masterTable) are dropped. The second talbe (childTable) has to wait 5 seconds too, but it doesn't.

[image: This is the parentTable with it's interval. ChildTable undefined is fine because the child Table isn't present now]

[image: The childTable is present. I know it drops a undefined, but It comes because I clean the interval first to prevent possible duplicates intervals ID]
[image: When I stop the server, the first table (databases) waits 5 secons and it has to be incremental when X number of errors (from databases only, masterTable) are dropped. The second talbe (childTable) has to wait 5 seconds too, but it doesn't.]

---

#### So...What I have to Do?

- I know that addChildTableInterval with 1000 and rowclicked probably is the problem, but I don't know how to change it.
- How I make the request incremental?

#### UPDATE: I SOLVED THE ISSUE

The issue with the 2 intervals is solved. The explanation? Quite easy. 
If you take a look at my code, you can see that I have a class called "ConsoleDataTable".

When I was accessing the me.childTableInterval, I was INSIDE ConsoleDatatable, but that wasn't my purpose! I want to be on addChildTable! So I changed the call to my object and...PROBLEM SOLVED! :D

You have to check that your current scope is your OBJECTIVE SCOPE. In other cases, you will have the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok people, I solved the issue with the 2 intervals. It was a thing related to the scope of me.

Comment: It's worthy to share the actual problem + solution here for future references.

Comment: I ment in the answer ;) users are encouraged to answer their own questions if they solve the problem themselves